# Fetch Only Row Randomly in Ascending order without repetition in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to fetch one row at a time on every load, I tried to use random function in mysql(rand()) but its fetching row randomly not one after another.

Suppose my table is given below:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
Name
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>John A</td></tr>
<tr><td>John C</td></tr>
<tr><td>John D</td></tr>
<tr><td>John T</td></tr>
<tr><td>John X</td></tr>
</table>
```

I had used below PHP code;

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `student` WHERE `status`='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $name;
}
```

So every time the Pages refreshes I get Different Row, but sometimes it get repeated.

Ex: 
1 Refresh : John D

2 Refresh : John X

3 Refresh : John A

4 refresh : John D

So the Output I want is that it should fetch row in order without repeating anyrow more times;

1 Refresh : John A

2 Refresh : John C

3 Refresh : John D

4 refresh : John T

5 refresh : John X

6 Refresh : John A

7 Refresh : John C

8 Refresh : John D

9 refresh : John T

10 refresh : John X

Comment: The expected result is simple ordering (paging with page size set to 1). Why do you use a random pick if you want simple ordering? Let me make it clear: if records appear in any prespecified order, then the selection is not random any longer. Your two criteria contradict each other.

Comment: If I set order to ASC/DESC it will fetch same row on every page refresh

Comment: Because you do not save which row was displayed before. You need to save that in your session and display the next using the `limit $x, 1` clause in your wuery

Comment: my solutions is that Why not pull all your ids first into a session array, choose a random index, look it up, then delete that index from the session array?

Comment: anyidea how to do it?

Comment: First edit your wuestion and clarify what you really want: random sample of 1 without (this is a duplicate question so I will immediately cast a close bote) repetition or ordered list one by one.

Answer (score -1):

You could refer here for [sorting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sorting-results.htm) the queries

```
SELECT column-list 
FROM table_name 
[WHERE condition] 
[ORDER BY column1, column2, .. columnN] [ASC | DESC];
```

Comment: No OP wants to get random username every time page refresh without repeating anyone.

Comment: Well, I think he can combine `RAND()` and `[ASC | DESC]` haha

Comment: @prakashtank you are right I want to fetch one row on every refresh but in order without repeating anyone

Comment: @RiyaPatel Does your database have duplicate data?

Comment: @RiyaPatel : it's usual to get repeated row because RAND() function randomly gets data without ordering.

Comment: Is there any way to get orderly without repeating row more times than other rows?